# Unable to edit single or structures, channels working fine after update to Craft 3

Tags: entries, craft3

Working in devMode, when trying to edit an existing single or structure entry, I get an InvalidArgument error

yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: Syntax error. in ...vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php:133

```
if (isset($availableErrors[$lastError])) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException($availableErrors[$lastError], $lastError);
}
```

I notice in Chrome tools I get a bunch of Craft is not defined errors any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Was an issue with my Simple.json redactor config

Was

```
{
    buttons: [bold, italic],
    toolbarFixed: true
}
```

Needed to be

```
{
    "buttons": ["bold", "italic"],
    "toolbarFixed": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same error. Something went wrong during the update to craft 3.4.

In my case, it had todo with the corrupted stored settings information in the database.

The solution was to remove the serialized content in the `info` table. You might want to safe it first though ;)
After I deleted the serialized settings and reloaded the admin page, craft rebuild it and everything works fine now.

Maybe this helps someone ;)

Comment: I had the same error message and also found this page (my Redactor configs are fine), something went from updating from 3.1 to 3.4 this morning